# Error " Index 2 out of bounds for length 2"

Tags: java

Estoy intentando hacer un código que calcule la mediana de las notas de cada uno de los estudiantes. Para representar las notas de cada estudiante se utiliza un array de 2D donde cada posición se corresponde a un estudiante y en cada elemento una nota. Por ejemplo:

```
[ [8,7,10,8.2] [6,4.2,8,9] ]
```

El primer estudiante tiene las notas: 8, 7, 10 y 8.2. Por lo tanto la mediana es: 8.3
El segundo estudiante tiene las notas: 6, 4.2, 8 y 9. Por lo tanto la mediana es: 6.8
El código debería devolver un array como el siguiente: [8.3, 6.8]

He hecho lo siguiente:

```
 public static double[] averageGradeByStudent(double[][] notes) {

        double sum[] = new double[8];
        double average[]= new double[8];

        for (int i=0; i < notes.length; i++){
            sum[i] = notes[i][0] + notes[i][1] + notes[i][2] + notes[i][3];
            average[i] = sum[i]/4;

            System.out.println(average[i]);
        }
        return average;
    }
```

Y contrasto los resultados con los siguientes tests:

```
void testAverageNoteByStudent() {
        assertArrayEquals(new double[] {4.2, 8.1, 9.4, 6.1, 4.7, 6.4, 6.0, 7.7}, PAC1Ex3.averageGradeByStudent(new double[][] {
                {2 ,4.5, 3, 7.3},
                {7.9, 7.5, 8, 9},
                {9.8, 8.8, 9, 10},
                {9.1, 3.8, 4.5, 7},
                {6.3, 5, 4.5, 3},
                {8, 7, 4, 6.6},
                {5, 7, 4, 8},
                {6, 10, 5.8, 9}}), 0);

        assertArrayEquals(new double[] {6.6, 7.9, 8.9, 9.6, 7.3, 6.5, 4.0}, PAC1Ex3.averageGradeByStudent(new double[][] {
                {8 ,5.2},
                {7.8, 8},
                {8.8, 9},
                {9.2, 10},
                {8, 6.6},
                {5, 8},
                {6, 2}}), 0);
        assertArrayEquals(new double[] {7.0, 7.5, 8.0, 8.5, 9.0}, PAC1Ex3.averageGradeByStudent(new double[][] {
                {8 ,6},
                {8 ,7},
                {8 ,8},
                {8 ,9},
                {8, 10}}), 0);
    }
```

Los resultados que estoy obteniendo son buenos, es decir, estoy obteniendo el vector de medias esperado:  `{4.2, 8.1, 9.4, 6.1, 4.7, 6.4, 6.0, 7.7}`

Sin embargo, no llego a hacer los siguientes test porque me muestra el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es porque el código está hecho específicamente para 4 notas, si le pasas menos que eso entonces produce error. Eso se soluciona sumando las notas y calculado el promedio de forma dinámica:

```
double [] sum = new double [notes.length];
double [] average = new double [notes.length];

for (int i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
        // ciclo para acumular los valores de notes[i] de forma dinamica
        for (int j = 0; j < notes[i].length; j++)
            sum[i] += notes[i][j];
        // la division se hace de forma dinamica segun la cantidad de elementos
        // en el arreglo
        average[i] = sum[i] / notes[i].length;
    
    
        System.out.println(average[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Tienes razón pero ahora estoy obteniendo el siguiente error: org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: array lengths differ, expected: <7> but was: <8> la tercera comprobación. Creo que es por la forma en como se declararon las variables sum y average.

Comment: podrias echarle un vistazo a este post? https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/488100/112550